# delete .gitignored files with rsync

Tags: rsync, git

I often need to use rsync to synchronize a local with a possible remote directory, while ignoring exactly all the files git would ignore because of its .gitignore configuration.

To do so, I am currently listing all files relevant to copy with git and then pipe them to rsync.

```
cd $source
{ git ls-files -coz --directory --exclude-standard
  printf '.git\0'
} | rsync --info=progress2 -ar0 --files-from=- ./ "$destination"
```

Leaving the parsing to git itself and then piping the file list to rsync has some advantages I depend on.

- The patterns to ignore files may be rather complex, also involving negation (`!inverse-pattern-to-include`), which rsync does not understand in this syntax.
- `.gitignore` files placed in subdirectories should also be taken into account. Rsync's `merge-dir` filter does not entirely allow to remodel this, because for rsync, the order of includes and excludes matters.
- Global git configuration files, like `.git/info/exclude`, are also considered.
- It can even work without a git repository initialized, one just has to point git to an empty repository with `--git-dir`.
- Repositories can be quite big, so specifying all the relevant files as rsync `--filter` `--exclude` or `--include` patterns is likely to burst the command line limit or severely slow down rsync. Using `--files-from` avoids this.

Now I need to improve this code fragment to support rsync's `--del` flag to remove all files from `$destination` that are missing from or excluded at `$source`. Unfortunately, it does not play well with `--files-from`. Is this possible without again comparing file lists from both ends?